# Checking answer in math game won't execute

Tags: javascript, html

This is a math practice game I am building that is using the random function to change the math problem numbers. The user will enter the answer into a text box and then check the answer by clicking the button called "check". The `fillElements()` function is working however i cannot get a response from the program when i click "check". I have sorted through a lot of mistakes thus far but this problem I can not see or understand.

```
<body onload="fillElements()">
<form action="math.html">
<ul>
    <li id="num"> </li>
    <li> +</li>
    <li id="num2"> </li>
    <li> =</li>
    <li><input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" /></li>
</ul>   
<button type="button" onclick="validate()">Check</button>
</form>
<script src="javaScript/math.JS"></script>

</body>
```

//JavaScript

```
var totalCorrect= 0;
var totalIncorrect= 0;
var score = math.round(totalCorrect/totalIncorrect);
var message= 'Congrats!, you scored:' + score + 'percent';




function fillElements() {
    firstNum = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
    secondNum = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
    var rand= Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);
    var rand2= Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);

    var el= document.getElementById('num');
     el.textContent = firstNum[rand];
    var el2= document.getElementById('num2');
     el2.textContent = secondNum[rand2];

    }

function validate() {
var userAnswer= number(document.getElementById('answer'));

if (num + num2 === userAnswer) {
    totalCorrect++;
    alert(message);
    fillElements();
    }
else {
    totalIncorrect++;
        alert(message);

}

}
```

Comment: Pop open your browser's javascript console and try running through it again.  For most browsers, the F12 key will show and hide the console.  You'll see errors show up if your code is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `number()` it's `Number()`

[Check here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)

Working code...

**HTML**

```
<form action="math.html">
<ul>
<li id="num"></li>
<li> +</li>
<li id="num2"></li>
<li> =</li>
<li><input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" /></li>
</ul>   
<button type="button" onclick="validate();">Check</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function(){
fillElements();
}


function fillElements() {
firstNum = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
secondNum = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
var rand= Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);
var rand2= Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);

var el= document.getElementById('num');
 el.textContent = firstNum[rand];
var el2= document.getElementById('num2');
 el2.textContent = secondNum[rand2];

}


var totalCorrect= 1;
var totalIncorrect= 1;

function validate() {

var userAnswer= Number(document.getElementById('answer').value);

var num = document.getElementById('num').textContent;
var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').textContent;
var valid = Number(num) + Number(num2);


if (valid === userAnswer) {
totalCorrect++;
var score = Math.round(totalCorrect/totalIncorrect);
var message= 'Congrats!, you scored:' + score + 'percent';
alert(message);
fillElements();
}else {
totalIncorrect++;

var score = Math.round(totalCorrect/totalIncorrect);
var message= 'Congrats!, you scored:' + score + 'percent';
    alert(message);

}

}
```

**Edit:** Don't use

```
var totalCorrect= 0;
var totalIncorrect= 0;
```

because if you score a point then it will print `infinity` => `Math.round(1/0);` try

```
var totalCorrect= 1;
var totalIncorrect= 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!....the only thing i did have to change was the window.onload = function(){fillElements()} to just window.onload= fillelements(); but again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've to get `value` of input to compare, not the `input` itself.
So replace the following

```
var userAnswer= number(document.getElementById('answer'));
```

with

```
var userAnswer= number(document.getElementById('answer').value);
```

Comment: thank you!, i did not know that. I added the .value to the end of my statement and my code still wont execute. I cannot help but think something is wrong maybe on my html side maybe. I can refresh the page and fill the "num" and "num2" elements with new numbers but i cant get the arithmetic to work and or my function validate() to work.

Comment: It's not `number()` it's `Number()`

Comment: I assumed `number` to be his custom function, bu anyway. @tim Collins. If this is the correct answer, please choose it

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensetive, so you need to use `Math.round`, not `math.round`:

```
var score = Math.round(totalCorrect/totalIncorrect);
```

To use the variables later, you need to declare them outside the function:

```
var rand, rand2;

function fillElements() {
  firstNum = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
  secondNum = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
  rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);
  rand2= Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);

  var el= document.getElementById('num');
  el.textContent = firstNum[rand];
  var el2= document.getElementById('num2');
  el2.textContent = secondNum[rand2];
```

}

To get the value from an input you need to use the `value` property. To convert it to a number you use `Number`, not `number`:

```
var userAnswer = Number(document.getElementById('answer').value);
```

To check the answer, use the variables that you set before. You haven't created any variables `num` and `num2`.

```
if (rand + rand2 === userAnswer) {
```